# How to keep navigation menu link styled persistently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four items in my navigation menu

```
<nav>
 <ul >
  <li><a href="/a.html">ITEM A</a></li>
  <li><a href="/b.html">ITEM B</a></li>
  <li><a href="/c.html">ITEM C</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Hovering or clicking any of these items changes their color. But the color is gone after page refresh. If a user clicks on `b.html`, I want the menu item B to have a different color when the page reloads.How can I achieve that?

Am I making my question clear?

Thanks.

Comment: localStorage can save some user settings if you want. But you need to write logic to store and load a users settings on page load.

Comment: The settings are not specific to a user. I want the color to be persistent for everyone like :active selector but still working after page reload.

Comment: add class to that li and style it ..

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: No, it didn't but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest jQuery-based answer I can think of is to retrieve the `href` attribute-value and test that the URL of the current page ends with that attribute-value:

```
// getting the current location:
var url = document.location.href;

// iterating over each <a> element using filter(), using a
// more specific selector will reduce the work undertaken:
$('a').filter(function(i, a) {
    // i: the index of the current <a> element within the
    //    jQuery collection;
    // a: the current <a> DOM node.

    // String.prototype.endsWith() returns a Boolean, true
    // if the supplied string (url) ends with the supplied
    // argument (the attribute-value of the 'href'
    // attribute of the current <a> element):
    return url.endsWith( a.getAttribute('href') );

// we add the 'activeClass' class-name to those elements
// retained in the collection, to provide a styling hook:
}).addClass('activeClass');
```

Or, in the (somewhat likely) event that the browser doesn't support `String.prototype.endsWith()`:

```
var url = document.location.href;
$('a').filter(function(i, a) {

    // retaining only those <a> elements whose
    // 'href' property (the absolute URL
    // derived from the <a> elements' href
    // attribute) is equal to the document location:
    return url == a.href;
}).addClass('activeClass');
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
var aElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')),
// or, in the event that ES6 Array.from() is unavailable:
// var aElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), 0),
    url = document.location.href;

aElements.filter(Function (currentAnchor) {
    return currentAnchor.href == url;
}).forEach(function (currentAnchor) {
    currentAnchor.classList.add('activeClass');
});
```

Obviously all the above approaches require that a class be defined in your CSS to style the found links, such as – but obviously adjust to your own taste/aesthetic – the following:

```
a:active,
a.activeClass {
    color: #f90;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

It's worth noting – albeit somewhat optimistically – that at some point in the future, the pseudo-class of `:local-link` might style an `<a>` element pointing at the current page, for example:

```
a:active,
a:local-link {
    color: #f90;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Though I'll note that, at the time of writing, this is not yet implemented, nor even *listed* on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Alocal-link).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:local-link` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#local-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter).

Comment: The `href` attribute may or may not be in the end. Therefore I replaced `endsWith` with `includes` but it gives me the error `url.includes is not a function`.

Comment: `indexOf` did not work either. It gave the same error. Just to be sure I used `console.log(url)` which gave me `Location {hash: "", search: "", pathname: "pathname", port: "", hostname: "hostname"…}`

It does not look like a string. Maybe that's the issue :).

Comment: It is working with `includes` now. I had to use `document.location.href` though.

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: It happens. Yours is probably the most details answer I have ever received from anyone here. :)

Comment: I aim to please! :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use pseudo classes of link to have different css like, hover, active, visited

e.g.

```
a {
  color:pink;
}
a:hover {
  color:red;
}

a:active {
  color:green;
}

a:visited {
  color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: @moped: Yahh, I just gave him idea what he could do with pseudo class, to give him idea, he will decide color as per his own requirements... ;) :P otherwhise uses pink for links :D :D